# Create an array from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a webpage where a user can select multiple items from a jquery list.

Based on the item(s) selected I need to add each item into the database.

When someone selects one item the value returned to my Javascript is similar to "4~2"

The value 4 would be used in my example for one column named "skill_id" in the database and the value 2 would be used for another column called "category_id" in the same row.

When someone selects two items it is comma-delimited and similar to "4~2,6~7" and so on if they select more than 2.

I'm thinking I need to do a for loop with an array or a jquery.each() function but not certain how the best way to approach this is.

Comment: Adding some code will gain the success of the answers ;)

Answer (score 16):

What you're looking for is the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```
"4~2,6~7".split(',') // ['4~2', '6~7']
```

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble yeah, this got me a "nice answer" badge ;o). Why did you start the bounty by the way?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you could extract the skill_id and category_id:

```
  $.each("4~2,6~7".split(','), function(index, value) {
      var nums = value.split("~");
      var skill_id = nums[0];
      var category_id = nums[1];
  });
```